# reading some part of string from cell array in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, copy

I want to copy some part of a string from a cell array and put it into another cell array in MATLAB.

For example, one struct is like this

```
{>eco:b0002 thrA; Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase 1 (EC:1.1.1.3 2.7.2.4); K12524 bifunctional aspartokinase / homoserine dehydrogenase 1 [EC:2.7.2.4 1.1.1.3] (N) atgcgagtgttgaa...},
```

I want to paste the

```
'>eco:b0002 thrA; Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase 1 (EC:1.1.1.3 2.7.2.4); K12524 bifunctional aspartokinase / homoserine dehydrogenase 1 [EC:2.7.2.4 1.1.1.3] (N)'
```

part of referring string into another cell array.

In each cell it begins with '>' and ends up with '(N)', as you see one of them in the example.

I can't find any helpful function to start with.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> str = '>eco:b0002 thrA; (N) atgcgagtgttgaa...';
>> result = regexp(str, '\>.+\(N\)', 'match');
>> result = result{1}
result =
>eco:b0002 thrA; (N)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [regular expression](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html).

Try for example:

```
> str = "> fooooo (N) bar baz"
> exp = "^>(.*)\\(N\\).*$"
> [tokens, matches] = regexp(str, exp, 'tokens', 'match')
> tokens{1}{1}
ans => foooooo
```

(Disclaimer: I tried the above in Octave, which *should* behave exactly the same).

Comment: I got an error in Matlab (even with single quotes instead of double qoutes). `tokens` is returned as empty

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a MATLAB installation at hand to experiment with the finer details of MATLAB's regexp dialect, but I see it's no longer necessary :)

Comment: I didn't see anything obvious to correct/suggest in your answer, so I wrote mine :-)